# Como podria animar el menu hamburguesa que viene por defecto en boostrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como podria hacer para mostrar una animacion del menu hamburguesa en boostrap que me muestre una x al desplegar el menu y no el tipico menu hamburguesa:

Cuando se abra el menu, se cambie el icono a una X y cuando doy click en la x se cierre el menu, tal como se muestra en la imagen:
De antemano gracias por su respuesta.

por ejemplo esto es lo que se muestra por defecto, el tipico menu hamburguesa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que quiero lograr aparece una X en vez del icono del menu hamburguesa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi poor ejemplo esto cuando lo llevan a un tamaño para celular y le dan click muestra un cambio en el boton ,mostrando una x, hay otros en donde aparecen ese cambio animado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La clase que usa bootstrap para el icono de ese menu es navbar-toggle.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el botón del menú con la clase:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
```

Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar esa clase por una que definas tu y luego en el CSS le agregas a esta clase la dirección de la imagen con la X. Como sigue en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
//El botón
<button class="imgX" (...)> </button>

//Y en el CSS:
.imgX {
background-image: url(images/imagenX.png);
}
```

Prueba así a ver si te resulta

Comment: Bien gracias, voy a probarlo.